# Automatically expiring variable

Tags: python, arrays, variables

How to implement an automatically expiring variable in python? For example, Let the program running For one hour. I want implement an array of 6 variables, each variable in array will be automatically deleted themselves after 10 mins. And after 1 hour, there will be no variable in the array.

Comment: This is pretty vague... What real problem are you trying to solve using this method, what have you tried so far, and how did it not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a background process that check how much time it's passed, and del the right item... or if you want to create a subclass of list wich deletes it's contens after a certain time you can do the same thing, just calling it in **init**

```
def __init__(self, time):
    #run subprocess to chek_espired elements
```

edit:

i wrote an example, but it can be done much better!

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self,elems,  expires_time):
        list.__init__(self, elems)
        self.created = time.time()
        self.expires_time = expires_time
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        t = time.time()
        print t -  self.created
        if t - self.created > self.expires_time:
            self.created += self.expires_time
            self.pop(index)
            self.__getitem__(index)
        return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

ps of course you can easily raise a personal error if the program try to get the index from an empty list

Comment: ah, there is a bug in the above code; it will delete only one element per time,  doesen't matter if it's passed 11 seconds (so he has to del 2 elemnts) however, it's easy to fix; i edited my post

Comment: What about elements that are added later to the list? Does this solution assume that no elements will be added once the list is initialized? If we keep adding elements, we must have a timestamp for each item rather than for the entire list

Answer (score 9):

I actually had to do this for dictionaries. Maybe you'll find the code useful:

```
"""Cache which has data that expires after a given period of time."""
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class KeyExpiredError(KeyError): pass 

def __hax():
    class NoArg: pass
    return NoArg()
NoArg = __hax()

class DataCache(object):
    def __init__(self, defaultExpireTime=timedelta(1, 0, 0), dbg=True):
        self.defaultExpireTime = defaultExpireTime

        self.cache = {}
        self.dbg = dbg

        self.processExpires = True

    def setProcessExpires(self, b):
        self.processExpires = b

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        c = self.cache[key]

        n = datetime.now()
        if (n - c['timestamp']) < c['expireTime'] or not self.processExpires:
            return c['data']

        del self.cache[key]

        if self.dbg:
            print "DataCache: Key %s expired" % repr(key)

        raise KeyExpiredError(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        try:
            self[key]
            return True
        except KeyError:
            return False

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.cache[key] = {
            'data': val,
            'timestamp': datetime.now(),
            'expireTime': self.defaultExpireTime,
            }

    def items(self):
        keys = list(self.cache)
        for k in keys:
            try:
                val = self[k]
                yield (k, val)                                             
            except:
                pass

    def get(self, key, default=NoArg, expired=NoArg):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyExpiredError:
            if expired is NoArg and default is not NoArg:
                return default
            if expired is NoArg: return None
            return expired
        except KeyError:
            if default is NoArg: return None
            return default

    def set(self, key, val, expireTime=None):
        if expireTime is None:
            expireTime = self.defaultExpireTime

        self.cache[key] = {
            'data': val,
            'timestamp': datetime.now(),
            'expireTime': expireTime,
            }

    def tryremove(self, key):
        if key in self.cache:
            del self.cache[key]
            return True
        return False

    #the following you can call without triggering any expirations
    def getTotalExpireTime(self, key):
        """Get the total amount of time the key will be in the cache for"""
        c = self.cache[key]
        return c['expireTime']

    def getExpirationTime(self, key):
        """Return the datetime when the given key will expire"""
        c = self.cache[key]
        return c['timestamp'] + c['expireTime']

    def getTimeRemaining(self, key):
        """Get the time left until the item will expire"""
        return self.getExpirationTime(key) - datetime.now()

    def getTimestamp(self, key):
        return self.cache[key]['timestamp']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cache)
```

Usage:

```
>>> dc = DataCache(timedelta(0, 5, 0)) #expire in 5 seconds
>>> dc[4] = 3
>>> dc[4]
3
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(5)
>>> dc[4]
DataCache: Key 4 expired
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    dc[4]
  File "datacache.py", line 35, in __getitem__
    raise KeyExpiredError(key)
KeyExpiredError: 4
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

Hmmm, seems weird, but possible.

Sounds like you need a class which records the time when `__init__` is called. Then, implement `__getitem__` to check the time when it is called, and only return the item if it's not too late. (It's probably easier to do this than to have a process "running in the background" which actively deletes items even when you don't ask for them.)

Comment: Sounds like a *much* better idea than using any threads or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the items in your array know about each other, because otherwise they'll all expire at the same time.

I think you want to create a subclass of list which deletes its contents after a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sched
import time
import threading

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def delete(_list):
    del _list[0]

for i in range(len(a)):
    scheduler.enter(60*10*i, 1, delete, (a,))

t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)

t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` module to clear the "array" every 10 minutes, by checking the time interval from when the script starts.

The last example on http://effbot.org/librarybook/time.htm point you in the right direction.