# container where values expire in python

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, containers

I am after a thread safe Python container where the values are automatically removed after a time. Does such a class exist?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927166/automatically-expiring-variable

Comment: I am after a thread safe class with timeouts for each value. That example uses a list and a global timeout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a thread safe version of ExpireCounter:

```
import datetime
import collections
import threading

class ExpireCounter:
    """Tracks how many events were added in the preceding time period
    """

    def __init__(self, timeout=1):
        self.lock=threading.Lock()        
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.events = collections.deque()

    def add(self,item):
        """Add event time
        """
        with self.lock:
            self.events.append(item)
            threading.Timer(self.timeout,self.expire).start()

    def __len__(self):
        """Return number of active events
        """
        with self.lock:
            return len(self.events)

    def expire(self):
        """Remove any expired events
        """
        with self.lock:
            self.events.popleft()

    def __str__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return str(self.events)
```

which can be used like this:

```
import time
c = ExpireCounter()
assert(len(c) == 0)
print(c)
# deque([])

c.add(datetime.datetime.now())
time.sleep(0.75)
c.add(datetime.datetime.now())    
assert(len(c) == 2)
print(c)
# deque([datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 19, 8, 50, 0, 91426), datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 19, 8, 50, 0, 842715)])

time.sleep(0.75)
assert(len(c) == 1)
print(c)
# deque([datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 19, 8, 50, 0, 842715)])
```

Comment: thanks! I like the threaded timeout. Was my example not thread safe? The docs say "deque is an alternative implementation of unbounded queues with fast atomic append() and popleft() operations that do not require locking."

Comment: @Plumo: I'm no expert at judging thread safety, but I think your version of ExpireCounter might not be thread safe. In the `add` method, the call to `datetime.now()` may not be followed immediately by the call to `self.events.append`. Imagine multiple threads calling the `add` method near-simultaneously. Lots of calls to `datetime.now`, but the results get appended to `self.events` in a jumbled order. If `self.events` is not chronologically ordered, then the while loop in the `expire` method may end too early. Thus, it may fail to `popleft` all the elements that have timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want an LRU cache.  Here's one I've been meaning to try out:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.lru

It seems to be thread safe.

Comment: no not LRU. I want a value to expire after exactly the given timeout regardless of how many values I have and whether I access them.

Comment: In that case, you could store an expiration time with each value.  What kind of container semantics do you want: list, set, dict, or something else?

Comment: not concerned with type of container as long as it is thread safe

Comment: +1 for Shane. Don't try to remove stuff from the container when it expires (especially if you have multiple threads); instead store an expiration time with each item and check to see if an item is expired when you retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less what I want for now:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import deque

class ExpireCounter:
    """Tracks how many events were added in the preceding time period
    """

    def __init__(self, timeout=timedelta(seconds=1)):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.events = deque()

    def add(self):
        """Add event time
        """
        self.events.append(datetime.now())

    def __len__(self):
        """Return number of active events
        """
        self.expire()
        return len(self.events)

    def expire(self):
        """Remove any expired events
        """
        now = datetime.now()
        try:
            while self.events[0] + self.timeout < now:
                self.events.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            pass # no more events


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    c = ExpireCounter()
    assert(len(c) == 0)
    c.inc()
    time.sleep(0.75)
    c.inc()
    assert(len(c) == 2)
    time.sleep(0.75)
    assert(len(c) == 1)
```