# How would you organize your data structure to pickup the last expiring item quickly in Python?

Tags: python

I want to create a process that store data with an expiration date (the format for the expiration data can change : timestamp, dateobject, timedelta, whatever) in [this fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927166/automatically-expiring-variable).

With a timer, I wish to depop regularly data that have expired.

If I got thousand of elements with an expiration date, what kind of data structure should I use to make quick insertions, findings and deletions ?

My first thougth is to use UTC timestamp and a [heapqueue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html?highlight=heap#heapq). The perfs are pretty good, but it's still O(log(n)) so it will increase with the number of items.

What does redis / memcache do to provide these operation with O(1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two approaches that should be combined - hit-and-miss + clean-up of all data (in a "offline" manner - not during a request).

On memcahce

> Memcache doesn’t evict keys when their expiration time expires, as doing so isn’t possible while still guaranteeing O(1) operation times. Instead expiration is more of a way to say how long until a key should be considered stale. When a GET is performed, Memcache checks if the key’s expiration time is still valid before returning it.

On redis

> Redis keys are expired in two ways: a passive way, and an active way.
>   A key is actively expired simply when some client tries to access it, and the key is found to be timed out.
>   Of course this is not enough as there are expired keys that will never be accessed again. This keys should be expired anyway, so periodically Redis test a few keys at random among keys with an expire set. All the keys that are already expired are deleted from the keyspace.

Side note - Hooray for probabilistic approaches

Here are the references on [memcache](http://www.memcachier.com/documentation/memcache-user-guide/) and on [redis](http://redis.io/commands/expire)

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting the data with expiration dates in order? If so a heapqueue will be slower than a linear queue, where it is O(1) to insert and O(1) to pop.

Comment: No, if I was able to insert it in order with O(1), I would have no problem to solve.