# Python expiring variable like redis

Tags: python, python-3.x

With Python, I want a key and value to be stored and dumped only for a certain period of time. Is it possible to do this without using redis? I have to do it without using TCP. As in the NGinx Shared Dict example

```
def set_store(key, value, expire):
    ...
    
def get_store(key):
    ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically expiring variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927166/automatically-expiring-variable)

Comment: You write a dictionary like class, that stores entries together with their expiration times and modify the access method to clean up. AFAIR Redis chooses a fixed number of random entries on every get and checks if they are expired.

Comment: I think I found the library I was looking for

https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ttldict

Answer (score 1):

Minimal implementation:

```py
import time
from datetime import timedelta

class TimedCache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storage = {}

    def set_store(self, key, value, expire: timedelta) -> None:
        self.storage[key] = (value, time.time() + expire.total_seconds())

    def get_store(self, key):
        value, expire_at = self.storage[key]
        if expire_at < time.time():
            raise KeyError(f"key {key!r} expired")
        return value
```

Usage:

```
cache = TimedCache()
# cache.get_store("test") == 42 #  raises KeyError: 'test'
cache.set_store("test", 42, timedelta(seconds=1))
cache.get_store("test") #  returns 42
time.sleep(1)
cache.get_store("test") #  raises KeyError: "key 'test' expired"
```

Recommended for testing only - other way better to use some production-ready library